# How to read java unicode byte string encoded with utf-8 in c++

Tags: c++, unicode, mongo-cxx-driver

I have proto message which is stored in mongo as string with below syntax

```
data.toByteString().toStringUtf8();
```

Which is nothing but unicode encoded as utf8.

Now i am trying to read the same in c++ side from mongo using below -

```c
std::wstring str(mongoData.get_utf8().value.to_string().begin(), mongoData.get_utf8().value.to_string().end());

String str1(boost::locale::conv::utf_to_utf<char>(str.c_str(), str.c_str()+str.size());
```

But doing above, str1 is giving corrupted data.

Please help what am doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: What is `String`? How do you know the data is "corrupted"? How do you check the data in `str1`? Please try to create a [mcve] to show us, and include some specific "input" and the expected as well as actual "output".

Comment: String is std::string.

When i parse from str1 using below-
protoMessage->ParseFromString(str1);
std::cout<<protoMessage->DebugString();

This gives corrupted string.

Answer (score 2):

Just *guessing* here: `mongoData.get_utf8().value.to_string()` returns a string *by value*.

That means the beginning and end iterators are totally unrelated as they come from different strings.

Simple solution to that is to create your own copy of the string and get the iterators from that copy:

```
auto mongo_string = mongoData.get_utf8().value.to_string();
std::wstring str(mongo_string.begin(), mongo_string().end());
```

Comment: I did the same as you suggested, but still the same corruption happenning